# HELP! need admin password or how to reset!

Tags: mac, macosx, administrator

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my macbook. i tried to do an update but it asked for an admin password that i dont have and never created. so i tried changing it through recovery mode, the only problem is i cant use the keyboard or mouse and soon as i enter recovery, even with a usb keyboard. any ideas guys?

Comment: Where did you try to update your Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

the admin password is the password of your user. if your user is administrator, you can enter your password and do the update. if your system has only one user, that user is admin.

Comment: it auto logins in to admin account! it says there is a password which i never created!